# Leaflet geoJSON

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, leafletjs

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой - не загружаются маркеры если сдвинуть карту, а если сразу начать зуммировть, то подгружаются маркеры нормально.

```
var layers = {
    Streets: L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets'),
};

layers.Streets.on('tileload', function (e) {
    var topLeft = map.layerPointToLatLng([e.tile._leaflet_pos.y, e.tile._leaflet_pos.x]);
    var topRight = map.layerPointToLatLng([e.tile._leaflet_pos.y, e.tile._leaflet_pos.x + layers.Streets.options.tileSize]);
    var downLeft = map.layerPointToLatLng([e.tile._leaflet_pos.y + layers.Streets.options.tileSize, e.tile._leaflet_pos.x]);
    var downRight = map.layerPointToLatLng([e.tile._leaflet_pos.y + layers.Streets.options.tileSize, e.tile._leaflet_pos.x + layers.Streets.options.tileSize]);
   _this.loadPointsOnMap(downLeft, topLeft, topRight, downRight, map);
});

loadPointsOnMap: function (setDownLeftPoint, setTopLeftPoint, setTopRightPoint, setDownRightPoint, map) {
    $.getJSON('utils/get-points-by-bound', {
        setDownLeftPoint: setDownLeftPoint.lng + ' ' + setDownLeftPoint.lat,
        setTopLeftPoint: setTopLeftPoint.lng + ' ' + setTopLeftPoint.lat,
        setTopRightPoint: setTopRightPoint.lng + ' ' + setTopRightPoint.lat,
        setDownRightPoint: setDownRightPoint.lng + ' ' + setDownRightPoint.lat
    }, function (data) {
        L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
    })
}
```

Ответ сервера для одной из точек

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример проблемы
http://g.recordit.co/FkcLu9A863.gif

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил. Оказывается, у меня в скрипте были перепутаны координаты. Отсылка на вопрос [Leaflet не загружаются полностью тайлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564975/leaflet-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B)

Отдельная благодарность @tutankhamun