# Leaflet не загружаются полностью тайлы

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, leafletjs

Здравствуйте! Почему могут не загружаться полностью маркеры на углах тайлов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
                    map = L.mapbox.map('map', null);

                        var layers = {
                            Streets: L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets'),
                        };

                        layers.Streets.addTo(map);

                        layers.Streets.on('tileload', function (e) {
                            var topLeft = map.layerPointToLatLng([e.tile._leaflet_pos.y, e.tile._leaflet_pos.x]);
                            L.marker([topLeft.lat, topLeft.lng]).addTo(map);
                          }
```

Comment: Кстати вы в `[e.tile._leaflet_pos.y, e.tile._leaflet_pos.x]` перепутали `x` и `y`

Comment: Собственно скорее всего в этом и заключена проблема. Вопрос можно удалять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Часть тайлов браузер может загружать из кеша. При этом событие `load` не вызывается.

Исправить это можно установив обработчик `tileloadstart` и проверяя свойство `complete`. Если `true` вызываете ваш обработчик, если нет, ждете пока не сработает событие `load`.

См. также:

1. [Cached images and the “load” event](http://mikefowler.me/2014/04/22/cached-images-load-event/) (на английском)

Comment: Всё же действительно, были перепутаны координаты. В очередной раз, большущее тебе спасибо!=)